# How can i pass a variable from my adapter to a fragment i instantiate in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-tabhost, fragment-tab-host

I followed a tutorial on getting started with tabhost and fragments, there is the link: https://medium.com/@eijaz/getting-started-with-tablayout-in-android-kotlin-bb7e21783761

But I got a problem, I want to send a value activityID to a fragment that my tabhost contains and I don't know how to do it.

I found on the internet that there is a method setArgument but no one of my objects contains this method.

Did I do something wrong ? Or could someone explain to me how to send my value from my ActivityTabHost to my fragment?

This is my ActivityTabHost.kt

```
import android.os.Bundle
import training.gutai.apps.gutai.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_tabhost.*
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.util.Log
import training.gutai.apps.gutai.models.TabHostAdapter


class ActivityTabHost : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabhost)

        val activityID = intent.extras.getInt("id")
        Log.d("Id", activityID.toString())
        val fragmentAdapter = TabHostAdapter(supportFragmentManager, activityID)
        viewpager_main.adapter = fragmentAdapter
        tabs_main.setupWithViewPager(viewpager_main)
    }
}
```

And this is my TabHostAdapter.kt :

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter
import training.gutai.apps.gutai.viewControllers.FirstFragment
import training.gutai.apps.gutai.viewControllers.SecondFragment

class TabHostAdapter(fm: FragmentManager, activityID : Int) :         FragmentPagerAdapter(fm) {

    val fm : FragmentManager = fm

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return when (position) {
            0 -> {
                FirstFragment()
            }
            else -> {
                SecondFragment()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return 2
    }

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence {
        return when (position) {
            0 -> "First Tab"
            else -> "Second Tab"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [FragmentPagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) is not having the `setArguments` method. The adapter is only holding the fragments. The [fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) are having the `setArguments` method.

In your `TabHostAdapter` you can set the value `activityID` to the desired fragment (`FirstFragment` or `SecondFragment`) using the `setArguments` method. Something like the following, in your `getItem` method, before returning the fragment:

```
val fragment = FirstFragment()
val args = Bundle()
args.putInt("activityID", activityID)
fragment.setArguments(args)
```